# "Use of possibly unassigned field" - depends on where variable is declared?

Tags: c#

I'm building a public class with a public method, which has the below line:

```
deviceInfo.Attributes.Size = Marshal.SizeOf(deviceInfo.Attributes);
```

deviceInfo is a variable based on the below structure:

```
public struct DeviceInfo
{
    public string DevicePathName;       // Path of the device
    public SafeFileHandle HidHandle;    // Handle used for communicating via hid.dll
    public HiddAttributes Attributes;   // HID Attributes
    public HidpCaps Capabilities;       // HID Capabilities
}
```

HiddAttributes is defined as:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct HiddAttributes
{
    public Int32 Size; // = sizeof (struct _HIDD_ATTRIBUTES) = 10
    public UInt16 VendorID;
    public UInt16 ProductID;
    public UInt16 VersionNumber;
}
```

If I declare my variable "deviceInfo" as a member of my class, then everything compiles ok:

```
private DeviceInfo deviceInfo;
```

But if I declare the variable "deviceInfo" as a local variable of my method, then "deviceInfo.Attributes" in the call to "Marshal.SizeOf(deviceInfo.Attributes)" is red underlined, and shows the error:

```
CS0170: Use of possibly unassigned field 'Attributes'.
```

Why to I get this error? Why do I get the error when declaring the variable locally in my method, and don't I get the error when the variable is declared as a member of my class?

Comment: Members are always considered initialized as part of construction (with whatever is the `default`), even if you don't specify any initializers yourself. The same is not true for local variables.

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert! I get it - obvious. If I use 'DeviceInfo deviceInfo = new DeviceInfo();' in the local declaration of the method, than I have an explicit initialization, and then it works as well. I'm learning... :-)